# htaccess RewriteRule - Slashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)/$ category.php?catgPLink=$1 [L]
```

This 404's without a slash on the end, what I'm wondering is how I could modify just this one
rule to work with or without a slash without messing up any of my other dynamic url's on this site.

Some other links I found to fix this using many lines of cond and rules then would break some of the other url's on the site.

An example of rule below the one above that breaks when I try some of the other fixes I've found.

```
RewriteRule ^projects/(. *)/(. *)\.html$ taskDetails.php?catgPLinkParent=$1&catgPLink=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)/?$ category.php?catgPLink=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Sameh, This got me pointed in the right direction, but it did not work by just adding the question mark:(.*)/?$ What I found in another post was this: ([^/]*)/?$ this portion fixed the problem and allowed for slash or no slash.